# How do I add the Buefy global object to Vue 3 CLI

Tags: javascript, vue-cli, bulma, vuejs3, buefy

I have been using the Buefy css library with Vue 3 and the CLI framework.
I installed it with npm install and have been using it with no problem.
That is until I wanted to use the dialog.alert feature.
The example on Buefy shown says to use,

```
 this.$Buefy.dialog.alert("My Alert Msg");
```

This does not work.  I don't have this.$Buefy, $Buefy, or Buefy as a defined object.

So I tried to define Buefy as a global object.
The Buefy example shown says to write the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Buefy from 'buefy'
import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css'
Vue.use(Buefy)
```

The example above does not say where to write this, so I tried to write it in my main.js file.
But the code in that file looks like nothing that will work with the suggested code.
The code in main.js is:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import './assets/scss/app.scss'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

There is no 'Vue' to use with Vue.use(Buefy)
App.use does not work either.

I am at a loss as to how to implement a global Buefy object that will allow me to use implement features like the alert dialog.

Answer (score -1):

I seems you are using vue 3 createApp method, with that, you can do this

```
 import { createApp } from 'vue'
 import App from './App.vue'
 import router from './router'
 import './assets/scss/app.scss'
 import Buefy from 'buefy'
 import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css'

 const app=createApp(App);
 app.use(router);
 app.use(Buefy);
 app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: When calling the modal, you should just do `this.$buefy.dialog.alert("My Alert Msg");` . Notice Buefy is not in capital

Comment: Emmanuel, thanks for answering. Sorry for the delay, was working on something else.
I put your suggested  code in main.js, exactly like you suggested.
The code that calls the alert is in a method in a Vue component.  When I npm run serve I get the error: " Cannot read property '$buefy' of undefined"

The only thing that clears the error is to rem out //app.use(Buefy)
I am guessing this is a Vue 3 error.

Comment: Buefy allows you to import components individually, instead of `this.$buefy.dialog.alert` just import them wherever you need them. ```import { DialogProgrammatic as Dialog } from 'buefy'
Dialog.alert('We can use confirm and prompt methods as well')```

Comment: Emmanuel, Thanks for all your help. I tried importing what you suggested into my main.js file

You didn't specify how to make Dialog a global, so I guessed and added the line: "app.use(Dialog)" also in my main.js file. 

My application will run with this unlike the Vue.use(Buefy) but now, when I write "this.$dialog.alert("Don't Do That");" in my function that is in the "sites.js" component file, I get the error msg: "Cannot read property 'alert' of undefined"

Comment: It wont be global for now, Buefy currently is not fully compatible with vue 3